# How to add a removable cover to a roof-hole?

Tags: roof, well-pump

I had to cut a 10" diameter hole in the roof of our pumphouse because the pump needed to be replaced, and the pipes attached to it are ~20ft long each.

[image: Pumphouse]
*Pipes being removed from pumphouse*

[image]
*Picture of hole from inside*

Now I need to repair this hole so the roof doesn't leak.  **What's the best way to do that?**  The pump guy said I could cover it up with a vent like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Broan-NuTone-3-in-to-4-in-Roof-Vent-Kit-for-Round-Duct-Steel-in-Black-RVK1A/100344509), but ideally whatever I use should have the ability to open/close so that when the pump needs replacing again in 10-20 years, I don't need to go through this all over again.

I've looked into windows, but they are extremely expensive, can't be opened from the outside, and I haven't found one anywhere near small enough to be a good fit.

Comment: look into the RV world

Answer (score 1):

> I've looked into windows, but they are extremely expensive, can't be opened from the outside, and I haven't found one anywhere near small enough to be a good fit.

Maybe a Gasketed Access Port would be appropriate? Not too expensive, open from the outside, and come in diameters less than 12".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Install a skylight that opens/removes

Windows are not made for use on roofs.

There are a variety of skylight assemblies on the market intended for installation in houses. Find one that pops or tilts up, and whose mechanism can be disassembled to remove the plexiglass panel.

You may have re-roof the building to make an effective join to the skylight.  It's up to you, I don't know if you care how much a well house leaks.

### Or, put a stovepipe there

with proper anti-rain baffles. I gather that an 8" stove pipe will suffice, or even 6" perhaps.

They make specific assemblies designed to pass through a roof.